# Facebook Business Manager Active Request not showing up

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I request to access a Facebook Page it states:

"Your Business Manager Already has an active request on this Page. You'll see a notification if the request is accepted."

But then when I go to my Business page to view the requests it doesn't show up.

I was able to get it to work through another account ('Colt' in the screenshot below) but not this one.

I am trying to do this through another person's facebook account (a client) who owns business page. When I try to add it (instead of request it, because the account owns it) I get the same error.

Thanks,

[image: Request Access]

[image]